# Optional template parameter combinatorials

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, default, specialization

I have a set of template specializations (C++11) that uses the base template below, where both *tPayLoad* and *tReturnType* is present:

`template <class tDerivedOperation, class tBridgeType, class tPayLoadType = void, class tReturnType = void>   class OperationT ...`

The 1st specialzation is when there is neither *tPayLoadType* nor *tReturnType*:

`template <class tDerivedOperation, class tBridgeType> class OperationT<tDerivedOperation, tBridgeType, void, void> ...`

The second specialization is when there is only *tPayLoadType*:

`template <class tDerivedOperation, class tBridgeType, class tPayLoadType> class OperationT<tDerivedOperation, tBridgeType, tPayLoadType, void> ...`

Finally, I want the 3rd case (4th combination), having no *tPayLoadType* but a *tReturnType*, and that is where the problem pops up. I can't use (I think):

`template <class tDerivedOperation, class tBridgeType, class tReturnType> class OperationT<tDerivedOperation, tBridgeType, void, tReturnType> ...`

since that is essentially the same as specialization 2. Anyone having an idea of how to do this, if it's even possible???

/N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following

```
#include <iostream>
template<class tDerivedOperation, class tBridgeType, class tPayLoadType = void, class tReturnType = void>
struct OperationT {
    static constexpr auto overload = "base";
};

template<class tDerivedOperation, class tBridgeType>
struct OperationT<tDerivedOperation, tBridgeType, void, void> {
    static constexpr auto overload = "both void";
};

template<class tDerivedOperation, class tBridgeType, class tPayLoadType>
struct OperationT<tDerivedOperation, tBridgeType, tPayLoadType, void> {
    static constexpr auto overload = "back void";
};

template<class tDerivedOperation, class tBridgeType, class tReturnType>
struct OperationT<tDerivedOperation, tBridgeType, void, tReturnType> {
    static constexpr auto overload = "front void";
};

int main() {
    std::cout << OperationT<int, int>::overload << '\n';
    std::cout << OperationT<int, int, int>::overload << '\n';
    std::cout << OperationT<int, int, void, int>::overload << '\n';
    std::cout << OperationT<int, int, int, int>::overload << '\n';
}
```

gives the output

```
both void
back void
front void
base
```

exactly as one would expect. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Ha, look at that. That was completely illogical to me. Thanks a lot.